# How to get cumulative sum of a calculated column ordered in ascending order within each group in SQL

Tags: sql, count, teradata, cumsum

I have the following table in Teradata:

| group1 | group2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | C |
| A | C |
| A | C |
| B | C |
| B | A |
| B | A |
| B | A |
| B | D |

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE student
(
group1 varchar(10),
group2 varchar(10)
)
NO PRIMARY INDEX
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO student values ('A','A');
INSERT INTO student values ('A','B');
INSERT INTO student values ('A','B');
INSERT INTO student values ('A','C');
INSERT INTO student values ('A','C');
INSERT INTO student values ('A','C');
INSERT INTO student values ('A','C');
INSERT INTO student values ('B','A');
INSERT INTO student values ('B','A');
INSERT INTO student values ('B','A');
INSERT INTO student values ('B','A');
INSERT INTO student values ('B','D');
```

I am trying to get a table as follows, where the percentage column should be ordered ascending before cumulative sum:

| group1 | group2 | count_both_groups | group1_count | percentage | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 1 | 7 | 0.143 | 0.143 |
| A | B | 2 | 7 | 0.286 | 0.429 |
| A | C | 4 | 7 | 0.571 | 1.000 |
| B | D | 1 | 5 | 0.200 | 0.200 |
| B | A | 4 | 5 | 0.800 | 1.000 |

I can get all columns right expect the last one with:

```
 SELECT 
    group1,
    group2,
    COUNT (*) count_both_groups,
    SUM (count_both_groups) OVER (PARTITION BY group1) AS group1_count,
    (0.000+count_both_groups)/group1_count as percentage
    FROM student
    GROUP BY group1,group2
    order BY group1,percentage;
```

To add last column as well, I try:

```
 SELECT 
    group1,
    group2,
    COUNT (*) count_both_groups,
    SUM (count_both_groups) OVER (PARTITION BY group1) AS group1_count,
    (0.000+count_both_groups)/group1_count as percentage,
    sum (percentage) over (partition by group1 order by count_both_groups asc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cumsum
    FROM student
    GROUP BY group1,group2;
```

I get the error:

```
Ordered Analytical Functions can not be nested.
```

Comment: Try wrapping your select by an outer select that would have the `order by` command.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single pass like so, I think:

```
  SELECT 
group1,
group2,
COUNT (*) count_both_groups,
SUM (count_both_groups) OVER (PARTITION BY group1) AS group1_count,
(0.000+count_both_groups)/group1_count as percentage,
sum (0.000+ count_both_groups) over (partition by group1 order by count_both_groups asc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)/group1_count cum_sum
FROM student
GROUP BY group1,group2
order BY group1,cum_sum;
```

Comment: This is essentially what I tried to do. Instead of 'percentage' you use the open expression to calculate it. When using 'percentage' I got the error: Ordered Analytical Functions can not be nested.

Any comment why that happens? 

Any idea why Teradata throws that error?

Comment: Because "percentage" calculation uses windowed SUM "group1_count" - you can't use that _inside_ another SUM at the same query nesting level.